# how implement an android sidebar menu?

Tags: android, android-menu

what is best solution to implement a sidebar menu like below ?
items of sidebar and the content of each section comes from server(count of items is variable)

- section list (in left side)is scrollable
- section item count can be more than 20 item
- i use MVVM

i want some advices about view implementation for best performance in implementation

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get help with complete code from Material Design. [And click here to visit the site](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/#usage)

Comment: thanks, what is your idea about loading content of each section ? in single fragment or in viewPager or ...?

Answer (score 0):

For section items at Right, you can use RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager.

For the section list (on the left side) There are two possibilities based on the UI requirements.

1. You can use Navigation view for left navigation menu but not appropriate if data is being loaded from the internet
2. You can use a RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager

On the other hand, if you'll use view pager that will not be good for performance since there can be even more then 10 lists.

So you can display both lists in a Fragment and load the data in the repository. And on response send data to fragment using Live data and ViewModel. update the RecyclerViews in live data observer. Update Contents based on selected section

[Read about recyclerview](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)
[Read about Navigation menu](https://material.io/develop/android/components/navigation-view/)

Answer (score 0):

In this situation i found the best solution to use recycler-view for left-hand sidebar menu(because this is easy to use and handle)

and i used single fragment to showing content for each sidebar-menu item and caching content for later use(click action by user)

I prefer do not use the navigation menu for three reason :

1. I need the fix menu with no sliding action (of course i know i can fix navigation menu with no sliding)
2. more important : I fill the sidebar menu items with data that comes from server and this easy to handle for recycler-view
3. It is easier to change the sidebar-menu view based on the data and user action with recycler-view